# User not redirecting to the page after registering but registration working successfully in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The problem here is that registration is working properly but it is not redirecting to certain page which i want.because to go to that page which is in another controller,  id should be set on session .bt even after setting id to session it not working .help me out thank you..here is the code

**controller**

```
      public function newregister()
      {   
      if($this->session->userdata("passenger_id"))
      return redirect("user/dashboard");
      $this->load->view('userregister');
      }
      public function register()
      {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Fullname', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[42]|trim|alpha_numeric_spaces');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[passengers.uname]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of birth', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|required|max_length[10]|min_length[10]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');   
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pword', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|matches[pword]');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
          if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $pdata=array(
            'passenger_id'=>$this->input->post('passenger_id'),
            'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
            'uname'=>$this->input->post('uname'),   
            'dob'=>$this->input->post('dob'),
            'gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
            'mobile'=>$this->input->post('mobile'),
            'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'pword'=>sha1($this->input->post('pword')),
            'confirmpword' =>sha1($this->input->post('confirmpword'))
        );

        if($this->user_model->user_validate($pdata))
        {   


            $this->session->set_userdata($pdata);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','You have successfully registered to SMS TravelBook... ');
            return redirect('user/dashboard');
        } 
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Sorry failed to register');
            return redirect('home/register');
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->newregister();
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
     public function user_validate($pdata)
     {
         return $this->db->insert('passengers',$pdata);
     }
```

Comment: When a new passenger is registered, you should set `session`, then redirect the passenger to the new page.

Comment: i did set session as you can see but its not working

Comment: have you tried removing `return` before `redirect`? Just use `redirect('user/dashboard');`

Comment: yes i tried but no difference.

Comment: Does `$this->input->post('passenger_id'),` has a value?

Comment: no it  is id from database when passenger is registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue seems to be that you're setting session before even saving data into the database. Also, keep in mind that **you shouldn't store passwords in session**, I've written the rectified code, comments are mentioned wherever necessary, you're free to tweak it according to your needs. Hope it helps you. 
**Controller**

```
  public function newregister()
  {   
      if($this->session->userdata("passenger_id")){
          redirect("user/dashboard");
      }else{
          $this->load->view('userregister');
      }
  }

  public function register()
  {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Fullname', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[42]|trim|alpha_numeric_spaces');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[passengers.uname]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of birth', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|required|max_length[10]|min_length[10]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');   
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pword', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|matches[pword]');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $pdata=array(
            'passenger_id' => '', // empty because no value yet(value not inserted in db)
            'fname'        => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'uname'        => $this->input->post('uname'),   
            'dob'          => $this->input->post('dob'),
            'gender'       => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'mobile'       => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'city'         => $this->input->post('city'),
            'email'        => $this->input->post('email'),
            'pword'        => sha1($this->input->post('pword')),
            'confirmpword' => sha1($this->input->post('confirmpword'))
        );
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $dbId = $this->user_model->user_validate($pdata); // get the inserted id

        if($dbId) // check if query was successful
        {   
            $pdata=array(
            'passenger_id' => $dbId,
            'fname'        => $this->input->post('fname'), // or $pdata['fname']
            'uname'        => $this->input->post('uname'), // or $pdata['uname']
            'dob'          => $this->input->post('dob'),   // ...
            'gender'       => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'mobile'       => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'city'         => $this->input->post('city'),
            'email'        => $this->input->post('email'),
            'pword'        => sha1($this->input->post('pword')), // avoid storing password in session
            'confirmpword' => sha1($this->input->post('confirmpword')) // avoid storing password in session
        );
            /* or you could just do - $pdata['passenger_id'] = $dbId;(because rest of the data is same) */

            $this->session->set_userdata($pdata);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','You have successfully registered to SMS TravelBook... ');
            redirect('user/dashboard');
        } 
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Sorry failed to register');
            redirect('home/register');
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->newregister();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
 public function user_validate($pdata)
 {
     return ($this->db->insert('passengers', $pdata)) ? $this->db->insert_id() : false; // return insert_id if successful else return false
 }
```

Comment: Thank you somuch sir.it is working now.Im student so i do mistakes.thank you for taking time out and helping me.

Comment: ya .you are right thanks.if u dont mind i have one more question sorry

Comment: Post another question, this way more people will help you.

Comment: i have posted...  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61811627/13473454